# Dijit path error

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, dijit.form

I have problems with Dijit classes, they just don't want to work. My code is not creating table around button and this button is not cute as it should bee. Probably sth with path but I'm not sure. 
I'm receiving this error: "Undefined attribute value (dijit/layout/TabContainer)." near buttons. My file is in the same folder as dojo, dijit, dojox.

This is how it should look like:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcKuJ.png

And this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tutorial: Hello Dojo!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <script src="dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        require([
            "dijit/form/Button",
            "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
            "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
            "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function(Button, TabContainer, ContentPane){
            var tc = new TabContainer({
                    style: {
                        height: "200px",
                        width: "400px"
                    },
                    id: "tc"
                }),
                atab = new ContentPane({
                    title: "A Tab",
                    closable: false,
                    id: "atab"
                }),
                myButton = new Button({
                    label: "Click Me!",
                    id: "myButton"
                });
            atab.addChild(myButton);
            tc.addChild(atab);
            tc.startup();
        });
</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">

    <div id="tc" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer"
            data-dojo-props="style: { height: '200px', width: '400px' }">
        <div id="atab" data-dojo-type="dojo/dijit/layout/ContentPane"
                data-dojo-props="title: 'A Tab', closable: false">
            <button type="button" id="myButton"
                    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">
                <span>Click Me!</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you've provided is employing two different ways of adding dijits to a page, but it's not actually following through with either of them.

Dijit has two mechanisms for instantiating widgets: programmatic and declarative. To use the programmatic approach, create widgets and add them to the page using JavaScript. Widgets are being created in the example's require callback, but they are never added to the page. To add them, place the tab container in the document using a `tc.placeAt(document.body);` call before the `tc.startup();`. (`placeAt` will accept any DOM node or node ID.)

To use the declarative approach, create the DOM structure and tag it with widget types, then tell Dojo's parser to parse the DOM. The example sets up the DOM structure, but never instructs Dojo to parse it, so dijits are never created. To finish out the declarative approach, you can do one of two things:

1) Remove the JS code entirely and add a `parseOnLoad:true` property to the `data-dojo-config` attribute.

```
<script src="dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true; parseOnLoad: true"></script>`
```

2) Load 'dojo/parser' and call `parser.parse()` in the require callback.

```
require([ 'dojo/parser', 'dojo/domReady!' ], function (parser) {
    parser.parse();
});
```

In any case, only one method for adding widgets should be employed -- either programmatic or declarative -- but not both.